# Rails method for totaling quantity of individual products sold across all completed orders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, shopping-cart

I have a rails app with shopping cart functionality and want to define a method that gets the total quantity of individual products sold across all completed orders. I tried doing

```
def total_product_sold (product)    
  product.line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.quantity } 
end
```

but this returns the total of all line items including those only placed in shopping cart and not ordered. I only want the total of items actually ordered.

I also tried using the `.where` method as follows

```
def total_product_sold (product)     
  product.line_items.to_a.sum   { |line_items.where("order > 0", params[:orders])|       line_items.quantity }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  scope :ordered, -> {
    where("ordered > 0")
  }
end`

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items
  def sold
    self.line_items.ordered
  end
end

Comment: Thanks you put me in the right direction with using scope. I updated the syntax to scope :completed_order, -> {where("order > 0")} then defined a method total_product_sold (product)     
   product.line_items.completed_order.to_a.sum   { |line_items| line_items.quantity } end. problem is now i get a SQL error :SQLite3::SQLException: near "order": syntax error: SELECT "line_items".* FROM "line_items"  WHERE "line_items"."product_id" = 1 AND (order > 0)

Comment: {where(line_items.order > 0")}